Git checkout fails for jenkins agent pod when EFS storage is used as workspace volume
I have attached a EFS volume as workspace volume to my jenkins agent pod.
When I try to run the job, it fails while cloning git repo.
Pod.yaml
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
spec:
  containers:
  - name: python
    image: python:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    tty: true
    command:
    - "/bin/sh"
    - "-c"
    - |
      git config --global --add safe.directory '*' &&
      sleep infinity
    volumeMounts:
    - name: ssh-key
      mountPath: /root/.ssh
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: "/mnt/ephemeral"
      name: "volume-0"
      readOnly: false
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
    workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
      fsGroup: 0
      runAsGroup: 0
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 1.2Gi
      limits:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 1.2Gi
  hostNetwork: false
  restartPolicy: "Never"
  serviceAccountName: "default"
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
    fsGroup: 0
    runAsGroup: 0
  volumes:
  - name: ssh-key
    secret:
      secretName: ssh-key-pvc
      defaultMode: 256
  - name: volume-0 
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: efs-pvc

Error message
The recommended git tool is: git
using credential b7f7c713-14e2-4339-9500-e31dd75a29c7
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/jobs/.git # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@github.com:anonymous/private-repo.git
    at PluginClassLoader for git//hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:997)
    at PluginClassLoader for git//hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1239)
    at PluginClassLoader for git//hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM._checkout(GitSCM.java:1310)
    at PluginClassLoader for git//hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1277)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:136)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:101)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:88)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-step-api//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at PluginClassLoader for opentelemetry-api//io.opentelemetry.context.Context.lambda$wrap$1(Context.java:212)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:anonymous/private-repo.git" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: not in a git directory

    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2846)
    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2766)
    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2761)
    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2051)
    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2063)
    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.setRemoteUrl(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1662)
    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.setRemoteUrl(GitAPI.java:180)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:986)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:961)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:907)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:225)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:391)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:81)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:140)
    ... 1 more
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from ip-192-168-192-137.ec2.internal/192.168.192.137:37014
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1923)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:384)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1112)
        at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:306)
        at PluginClassLoader for git-client/jdk.proxy126/jdk.proxy126.$Proxy281.setRemoteUrl(Unknown Source)
        at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl.setRemoteUrl(RemoteGitImpl.java:348)
        at PluginClassLoader for git//hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:985)
        at PluginClassLoader for git//hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1239)
        at PluginClassLoader for git//hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM._checkout(GitSCM.java:1310)
        at PluginClassLoader for git//hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1277)
        at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:136)
        at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:101)
        at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:88)
        at PluginClassLoader for workflow-step-api//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at PluginClassLoader for opentelemetry-api//io.opentelemetry.context.Context.lambda$wrap$1(Context.java:212)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE

Grovy script
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            label 'pipeline'
            yamlFile 'Pod.yaml'
            defaultContainer 'python'
        workspaceVolume persistentVolumeClaimWorkspaceVolume(claimName: 'efs-pvc', readOnly: false)
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Setup Pre-Requisites') {
             script{
               sh "ls -lart"
             }
         }
    }
}

I have also mounted the ssh key that does have the access to clone repo. Also python image that I am using does have git in it. It is a custom build image.
Can someone please let me know what am I missing here?
Thanks in advance.
